# card.io will not compile on 64bit iPhone 5s armv7s

Tags: ios7, armv7, card.io

I'm having trouble compiling card.io on an iPhone 5s in 64bit mode (armv7s). It will compile on the simulator just finw. I am using Xcode 5.

Here is my error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
      -[CardIOVideoFrame process] in libCardIO.a(CardIOVideoFrame.o)
  "_CMGetAttachment", referenced from:
      -[CardIOVideoStream captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libCardIO.a(CardIOVideoStream.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
```

Answer (score 6):

Although, as @tomwhipple implied, you'll eventually run into other problems if you try to incorporate the current version of card.io into a 64-bit app, the particular error message you're getting now is due to something else.

Specifically, you must include the CoreMedia framework in your app's project.

See https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK for a complete list of the frameworks that you need to include.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Tom. I had added the frameworks but did so when xCode 5 was in beta. I deleted them and relinked with xCode GM and got closer. Then I added ImageIO.framework which was not required but I got it to compile. I also upgraded the device to iOS 7.0.3 that morning so I am not clear what actually did the trick.

Comment: We have now released a 64-bit compatible version of the card.io library (version 3.4.0) at https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK

Comment: Thanks Dave. I will give this a test run tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 0):

A 64 bit version of card.io is under development, but not yet released. We'll update [this Github issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/47) when it's ready.